# What does "cannot change store front information" mean in my App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

[image: You cannot change the store front information for your account at this time.]

How can I fix this problem? I wanted to change my App Store’s country but it ended up like that and now can’t download any apps.

Answer (score 1):

Before updating your country/region, you must first spend your store credit, cancel your subscriptions (e.g. to apps or iCloud), and ensure that you don't have any outstanding payments. You must also have a payment method for the new country/region you select. Also see [this guidance](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389) from Apple.

Comment: This is a good list of things to check. I also recommend opening a case with support to be sure if you think the situation may have changed before terminating all subscriptions. The Apple ones seem less likely to need cancelling if they offer the same services in both regions.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a temporary throttle or something permanent. I would open a case with Apple support and they can look up your specific account and assist.

- https://support.apple.com/apps

As long as you haven’t violated any of the rules, this should be a quick fix. If you didn’t provide correct information, it might be harder to solve if Apple detects things that are against the store terms.